# How to solve the undefined data issue when calling d3.layout.histogram().bins(...)(...)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Based on the example [Histogram chart using d3js](http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/8916402) that uses [d3.v3.min.js](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js) I create a histogram too. However, when calling the snippet:

```
// Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    (values);
if (angular.isUndefined(data) || data.length === 0) {
    // what now???
}
```

and if values has only one unique value (which can happen in my use-cases), then the above will result in undefined data e.g. when `var values = [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]`

Is there a way to make sure that I always get at least one valid bin rather than undefined data for this border case?

**UPDATE**: I have prepared [the following JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81kbL9z7/5/) that reproduces the issue. Just make sure to open the console to see the error and callstack e.g. in IE F12 or in Firefox use Developer Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of you problem is using `x.ticks` to set your bins.  When you only have one value this results in `min` and `max` being the same value and you have no domain here:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([min, max])
  .range([0, width]);
```

You could prevent this with a simple check:

```
var max = d3.max(values);
var min = d3.min(values);
if (max === min){
    max += 0.1;
  min -= 0.1;
}    
var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([min, max])
      .range([0, width]);
```

Running code:

```js
var color = "steelblue";

//var values = d3.range(1000).map(d3.random.normal(20, 5));
var values = d3.range(1000).map(function (idx) {return 1.0; });

// A formatter for counts.
var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var max = d3.max(values);
var min = d3.min(values);

if (max === min){
 max += 0.1;
  min -= 0.1;
}

var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([min, max])
      .range([0, width]);

var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    (values);
    
    console.log(data)

var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.length});
var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.length});
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([yMin, yMax])
            .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.y) });

bar.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("x", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

/*
* Adding refresh method to reload new data
*/
function refresh(values){
  // var values = d3.range(1000).map(d3.random.normal(20, 5));
  var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    (values);

  // Reset y domain using new data
  var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.length});
  var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.length});
  y.domain([0, yMax]);
  var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([yMin, yMax])
              .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

  var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

  // Remove object with data
  bar.exit().remove();

  bar.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

  bar.select("rect")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.y) });

  bar.select("text")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.bar rect {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar text {
  fill: #999999;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```